# Change True/False boolean value to "Occupied" label

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression

Change the label for a boolean: Instead of "True" and "False" I want the label to display "Occupied."

I have tried many iterations of this expression.  Nothing has worked.

```
Case when "Field Name" = "TRUE" THEN "Occupied"
Else Null
End
```

Comment: Does the field contain strings or some boolean type? You're checking against a string there.

Comment: TRUE  shouldn't be between quotes if it is a boolean, if it is a string it should be in single quotes 'TRUE', "TRUE" would be the name of a field

Answer (score 1):

You need to use single quotes, both for the value `'true'` - should it be saved as a string in `"Field Name"` (as explained by @Elio Diaz) - and for the word `'Occupied'` otherwise the label would contain the value of the column `"Occupied"`, which is unlikely to exist.

Let's note that booleans can be represented in different ways. For instance if you are using Postgres the syntax would be

```
Case when "Field_Name" = 't' THEN 'Occupied'
  Else NULL
End
```